# Export original 30fps video to 60fps

Tags: video-editor, openshot, framerate

If I had 30fps original video, than edited it in Openshot, would there be any quality difference if I exported it to 60fps instead of 30fps?

Answer (score 1):

No... There is no way you can restore lost data.

Comment: I'm asking because 30fps exporting saves my time, so I'll go with 30.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the original 30fps video will still be 30fps (technically 60, but each frame is displayed twice).

But **Yes**, transitions will be rendered in 60fps.